# My regular expression for extracting emails from resumes is also extracting phone numbers from these resumes

Tags: python, regex, email, robotframework

I created a regular expression to extract emails from resumes. However, it is also extracting phone numbers from these resumes. How can I solve this?  Obs:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Examples:

```
number 5579999644373
email paulosena91@hotmail.com
```

Correctly matched: `paulosena91@hotmail.com`

Incorrectly matched: `5579999644373paulosena91@hotmail.com`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show some examples. Include ones that (1) are correctly matched, (2) correctly not matched (3) incorrectly matched and (4) incorrectly not matched. Perhaps two examples of each.

Comment: I don't see how it could be getting that incorrect match, it doesn't appear in the example input.

Comment: You have to use a more fleshed out email regex closer to the spec. Even then there is _BLEED_ from boundary info text. This is something not really do-able in free-form text. Let me say that in different terms, the only way to validate email is to test send. Resume be damned.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex is running wild.  Tame it with more deliberate character classes and more boundaries.

1. matching the email prefix:

- many of these chars are not accepted in an email.

`[a-z0-9!#$%&'+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)`

Establish where the pattern is going to start matching, then make a succinct char class and be greedy to match as many instances as there are.

`start here`^ `here is my custom class`[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-] `I am being very greedy`+`

2. matching the at symbol

@

3. matching the domain

`(?:a-z0-9?\.)+a-z0-9?`

- You don't need any look ahead/behind and state when the pattern should stop matching ($)

Here is a solid regex for matching an email (from tutorialspoint):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$`
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/checking-for-valid-email-address-using-regular-expressions-in-java

Comment: "*Here is a solid regex for matching an email*": That regex is way too simplistic. See *[How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378)* for the real thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.

```
\b[\w.+-]+@[\w.-]+\b
```